# What is the derivation for the formula for Bels?

Tags: acoustics

For my project where I explore the relationship between the sine graphs of notes and their dissonance, I have to also talk about decibels and pressure. The steps I have taken to derive the decibel formula are shown below:

$$ P_b = \log\frac{P_{Pa}}{2\times10^{-5}} $$

The value of $2\times10^{−5}$ represents the pressure of the smallest sound we can hear, which is the baseline to get the ratios to calculate pressure in bels. Decibels would mean that the equation is multiplied by $10$, so we get:

$$ P_{db} = 10\log\frac{P_{Pa}}{2\times10^{-5}} $$

Now the original formula I found on [this website](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-physics/chapter/sound-intensity-and-level/#:%7E:text=Sound%20Intensity-,Sound%20intensity%20can%20be%20found%20from%20the%20following%20equation%3AI,w%20%E2%80%93%20speed%20of%20observed%20sound).

but I haven't been able to find a derivation for the formula for $P_b$, so I'm really stumped here.

Answer (score 2):

The [decibel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) is, as the prefix *deci* suggests, one tenth of a bel. So

$$P_{b} = 10 P_{db}$$

Decibel is used as a working unit instead of bel because it is a more convenient measure. An increase of one bel corresponds to an increase in intensity by a factor of $10$, whereas an increase of one decibel corresponds to an increase in intensity by a factor of $10^{0.1}\approx 1.259$.

Also, note that the ratios in both formulae should be ratios of power per unit area or intensity, *not* ratios of pressures. Intensity is proportional to the *square* of the peak-to-peak pressure change.

Comment: Right, but is there anyway to figure out how to derive the actual formula for the bel itself? like why is the formula what it is?

Comment: There is no derivation - the formula for the bel or the decibel is a *definition*. It is a useful definition because the human perception of the loudness of a sound is proportional to the logarithm of its intensity.